# How do I fix this solidity compiler error?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

Here is the relevant code. uint256 public assetCount is the problem:

```
contract FractionalRealEstate {
    struct Asset {
        address owner;
        string description;
        uint256 totalShares;
        uint256 pricePerShare;
    }
    
    struct Order {
        address orderOwner;
        uint256 assetId;
        uint256 shareCount;
    }
    
    mapping(uint256 => Asset) public assets;
    mapping(uint256 => Order[]) public buyOrders;
    mapping(uint256 => Order[]) public sellOrders;
    uint256 public assetCount;

    ERC20 public token;
    address public owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed; // Chainlink price feed contract
    

    constructor(address _tokenAddress, address _priceFeed) {
        token = ERC20(_tokenAddress);
        owner = msg.sender;
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function.");
        _;
    }
    
    function registerAsset(string description, uint256 price, uint256 shares) external onlyOwner {
        require(shares > 0, "Shares must be greater than 0.");
        assetCount++;
        assets[assetCount] = Asset(msg.sender, description, price, shares);
        
        emit RegisterAsset(description, price, shares);
    }
```

And here is the compiler error:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/FractionalRealEstate.sol

ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
  --> project:/contracts/FractionalRealEstate.sol:37:1:
   |
37 |     uint256 public assetCount;
   | ^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.9.2 (core: 5.9.2)
Node v18.16.0
```

I've tried setting assetCount equal to 0 and equal to 1 and it did not help either way. Thanks in advance!

I tried to initiate assetCount, but the compiler wouldn't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

- you should have proper imports for `ERC20` and `AggregatorV3Interface`

  ```
  ERC20 public token;

  AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed; // Chainlink price feed contract
  ```
- you have 2 errors in

`registerAsset`

```
 // data location should be memory for string
function registerAsset(string memory description, uint256 price, uint256 shares) external onlyOwner {
    require(shares > 0, "Shares must be greater than 0.");
    assetCount++;
    assets[assetCount] = Asset(msg.sender, description, price, shares);
    // you did not define registerAsset event. 
    // emit RegisterAsset(description, price, shares);
}
```

after correcting those, your code will compile.

Also in your post, you did not close the parantheses for the contract. you shoud have closing "}" at the end